# Изменение данных формы между приходом данных и их валидацией

Tags: symfony2

Нужно перед валидацией формы изменить некоторые данные в пришедшей форме, но в гугле поискал - максимум слушатель формы нашел. в котором можно добавить поле например, но если пытаюсь изменить данные, то получаю ошибку: You cannot change the data of a submitted form

Answer (score 1):

Все, нашел:

```
$builder->addEventListener(
    FormEvents::BIND,
    function (FormEvent $formEvent) {
        /** @var $user User */
        $user = $formEvent->getData();

        /** @var $form Form */
        $form = $formEvent->getForm();

        //Меняем значение
        $user->setCabinet(1);

        dump($user);
    }
);
```